# How to create a one-to-one relationship between an Input and SimpleRNN layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a 2-layer simple RNN model with Keras in which I can directly feed data into the first layer. As I understand it, cells in an RNN are fully connected with their input with the standard Keras layer. For example, if I define an input with 4 features and 1 timestep, connected to a SimpleRNN with 4 cells as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(1, 4)))
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(4, use_bias=False, return_sequences=True))

model.summary()
```

I will get:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (None, 1, 4)              32        
=================================================================
Total params: 32
Trainable params: 32
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Which makes sense. There are 4x4 recurrent connections in the SimpleRNN, and 4x4 connections between the input and the 4 RNN cells, so we get 32 trainable params (ignoring bias terms).

**However, I would like to structure my network so that each input feature is connected to only one cell in the RNN, as in the diagram below:**

[image]

Is there any way to do this in Keras? For example removing specific connections between layers?

Comment: I would change RNN to Dense layer and train with a custom loop to add recurrency

Comment: @Andrey a Dense layer would still be fully connected to its inputs though no? A standard dense layer would not produce the connection pattern I need as far as I understand

Comment: as you described - RNN has two matrices: the first matrix - to convert input to RNN dimension, the second - to multiply the input every recurrency step. You can not remove the second one (it is a necessary part of RNN). But you can remove the first as I suggested